# Swift Conditional Conformance with Any

Tags: swift

Let's assume an array of `Result`. We want the array to be reduced to a `Result` of an array. For example:

```
let z: [Result<Int, Error>] = [
    .success(1),
    .success(2),
    .success(3),
]
print(z.reduced())
```

gives:

```
success([1,2,3])
```

and

```
let z: [Result<Int, Error>] = [
    .success(1),
    .success(2),
    .success(3),
    .failure(MyError.blah),
]
print(z.reduced())
```

gives:

```
failure(MyError.blah)
```

I tried to implement it as an extension to Array like this:

```
extension Array where Element == Result<Any, Error> {
    func reduced() -> Result<[Any], Error> {
        return self.reduce(.success([Any]())) { (accumulator, result) -> Result<[Any], Error> in
            switch accumulator {
            case .failure(_):
                return accumulator
            case .success(let array):
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    return .failure(error)
                case .success(let value):
                    var newArray = array
                    newArray.append(value)
                    return .success(newArray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
print(z.reduced())
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:54:9: error: referencing instance method 'reduced()' on 'Array' requires the types 'Result<Int, Error>' and 'Result<Any, Error>' be equivalent
print(z.reduced())
        ^

MyPlayground.playground:34:1: note: where 'Element' = 'Result<Int, Error>'
extension Array where Element == Result<Any, Error> {
^
```

How to solve the error? Isn't `Int` supposed to match `Any`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic method and remove the constraint from the extension:

```
extension Sequence {
    func reduced<T>() -> Result<[T], Error> where Element == Result<T, Error> {
        reduce(.success([])) {
            switch $0 {
            case .failure: return $0
            case let .success(array):
                switch $1 {
                case let .failure(error): return .failure(error)
                case let .success(value): return .success(array + CollectionOfOne(value))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Btw you can also use a plain loop and provide an early exit at the first failure:

```
extension Sequence {
    func reduced<T>() -> Result<[T], Error> where Element == Result<T, Error> {
        var array: [T] = []
        for result in self {
            switch result {
            case let .failure(error): return .failure(error)
            case let .success(value): array.append(value)
            }
        }
        return .success(array)
    }
}
```

A more concise approach would be to create a generic method that throws or return an array with all successes:

```
extension Sequence {
    func successes<T, E>() throws -> [T] where Element == Result<T, E>, E: Error {
        try map { try $0.get() }
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let z: [Result<Int, MyError>] = [.success(1),
                               .success(2),
                               .success(3)] //,
                               //.failure(.blah)]
do {
    let successes = try z.successes()
    print(successes)  // [1, 2, 3]
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great detailed answer. Building on top of `successes<T, E>()`, I can make it use `Result` only (i.e. no exception) with: ```return .init { () -> [T] in try map { try $0.get() } }```

Answer (score 3):

You can move constraints to the function to make it generic:

```
extension Array {
    func reduced<T>() -> Result<[T], Error> where Element == Result<T, Error> {
        return self.reduce(.success([T]())) { accumulator, result in
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note: A variable of type `Int` will not match `Any` as it's a different type. Variables of type `Any` need to be casted down to `Int`.